# ValueError taking dot product of two sparse matrices in SciPy

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to take the dot product of two lil_matrix sparse matrices that are approx. 100,000 x 50,000 and 50,000 x 100,000 respectively.

```
from scipy import sparse
a = sparse.lil_matrix((100000, 50000))
b = sparse.lil_matrix((50000, 100000))

c = a.dot(b)
```

and getting this error:

```
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 211, in dot
 return self * other
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 247, in __mul__
 return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 300, in      _mul_sparse_matrix
 return self.tocsr()._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 290, in _mul_sparse_matrix
 indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=np.intc)
 ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

Any ideas on what might be happening - running this on a machine with about 64GB of ram, and using about 13GB when executing the dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bad error message, but the "problem" quite simply is that your resulting matrix would be too big (has too many nonzero elements, not its dimension).

Scipy uses `int32` to store `indptr` and `indices` for the sparse formats. This means that your sparsematrix cannot have more then (approximatly) 2^31 nonzero elements. Maybe you could change the code in scipy to use `int64` or `uint32`, if this is not just a toy problem anyways. But maybe the use of sparse matrixes is not the best solution for solving this anyways?

**EDIT:** This is solved in the new scipy versions AFIAK.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @seberg's answer.

There are two issues related to this on github.com/scipy/scipy.

[Issue #1833](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1833#ref-issue-13651914) (marked closed April 2013) and [Issue #442](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/442) with some pull requests that haven't been merged (Nov 2013 - SciPy version 0.13.1) due to some missing tests etc. You should be able to pull those into your own installation and compile a version that supports larger sparse matrices.